# Como adicionar classe ="active"

Tags: react

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

const isActive= (history, path) => {
    if (history.location.pathname === path) return { active: 'active' }
    else return { color: 'pink' }
}

const App= ({ history }) => (
    <nav id="sidebar" className="fixed pt-3">
        <ul className="custom-scrollbar">
           
            <li><Link to="/dashboard" className={isActive(history, "/dashboard")}><span className="ti-home mr-3"></span>Home</Link></li>
           
        </ul>
    </nav>
)

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que você está retornando um objeto para o atributo 'className' do seu elemento, o correto seria retornar apenas a string 'active':

```
const isActive= (history, path) => {
  if (history.location.pathname === path) return 'active'
  else return 'pink'
}
```

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Não funcionou Maycon

Comment: Tenta tirar as chaves do className: <li><Link to="/dashboard" className=isActive(history, "/dashboard")><span className="ti-home mr-3"></span>Home</Link></li>

Comment: Senão der certo tenta assim: <li><Link to="/dashboard" className={history.location.pathname == "/dashboard" ? 'active' : 'pink'}><span className="ti-home mr-3"></span>Home</Link></li>

Comment: Agora siim! muito obrigado!!!!